# Haskell binary trees traversal order with fold

Tags: haskell, binary-tree, fold, inorder, preorder

I defined my own Data Type `BinTree`, which describes my binary trees:

```
data BinTree a = Empty | Node a (BinTree a) (BinTree a) deriving (Show,Eq)
```

After that I implemented three sort-functions for the binary trees: `preorder`, `inorder` and `postorder`:

```
preorder :: BinTree a -> [a]
preorder Empty = []
preorder (Node x lt rt) = [x] ++ preorder lt ++ preorder rt

inorder :: BinTree  a -> [a]
inorder Empty = []
inorder (Node x lt rt) = inorder lt ++ [x] ++ inorder rt

postorder :: BinTree a -> [a]
postorder Empty = []
postorder (Node x lt rt) = postorder lt ++ postorder rt ++ [x]
```

To improve my order-functions, I implemented the `foldTree` function (which works as a normal `foldr` function, but with binary trees):

```
foldTree :: (a -> b -> b -> b) -> b -> BinTree -> b
    foldTree f e Empty = e
    foldTree f e (Node x lt rt) = f x (foldTree f e lt) (foldTree f e rt)
```

And now I got stuck, because I cant't figure out how to combine the order-functions with the `foldTree`.

Can someone give me a hint please?

Answer (score 0):

If by "combine" you mean implement each of the three functions using the last one, then this [my recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65969250/849891) seems to  be of use, e.g.

```
preorder  t  =  foldTree (\a l r -> (a :) . l . r) id t []
inorder   t  =  foldTree (\a l r -> l . (a :) . r) id t []
postorder t  =  foldTree (\a l r -> l . r . (a :)) id t []
```

Trying it out:

```
> t = Node 1 (Node 2 Empty (Node 3 Empty Empty)) (Node 4 (Node 5 Empty Empty) Empty)
{-
                 1
        2                 4
     .      3         5       .
          .   .     .   .
-}

> inorder t
[2,3,1,5,4]

> preorder t
[1,2,3,4,5]

> postorder t
[3,2,5,4,1]
```

The correct type of your function is, of course,

```
foldTree :: (a -> b -> b -> b) -> b -> BinTree a -> b
--                                            ^^^
```